# How do I choose the right classes to be drawn in a class diagram?

Tags: uml

For example: if I'm modeling a system that handles the inscription of students in a library and the documents in it, should I create a class for the library even though I have only ONE library?

Answer (score 2):

**In layman's terms:**

- Object oriented modeling is about modeling the real world to a certain degree of abstraction.
- In the domain of your problem the library is a thing.
- If you are modeling a system that handles the inscription of students in a library, it's quite obvious that you should at least have a library class and a student class.
- The library is so important that you mention it in the exposition of the problem. So, yes you should have a library class.
- How many instances of a class will you have when the program is running is not a criteria to determine whether or not such class should exist.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. How would a clock work if you leave out only a single part?

The reason you create a class model is that you show how things work together. And if you got a single instance, you still need it. And thus you have to show it.